# How to schedule MIDI events at "sample accurate" times?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, audiounit, audiotoolbox, auv3

I'm trying to build a sequencer app on iOS. There's a sample on the Apple Developer website that makes an audio unit play a repeating scale, here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/incorporating_audio_effects_and_instruments

In the sample code, there's a file "SimplePlayEngine.swift", with a class "InstrumentPlayer" which handles sending MIDI events to the selected audio unit. It spawns a thread with a loop that iterates through the scale. It sends a MIDI Note On message by calling the audio unit's AUScheduleMIDIEventBlock, sleeps the thread for a short time, sends a Note Off, and repeats.

Here's an abridged version:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
    ...
    while self.isPlaying {
        // cbytes is set to MIDI Note On message
        ...
        self.audioUnit.scheduleMIDIEventBlock!(AUEventSampleTimeImmediate, 0, 3, cbytes)
        usleep(useconds_t(0.2 * 1e6))
        ...
        // cbytes is now MIDI Note Off message
        self.noteBlock(AUEventSampleTimeImmediate, 0, 3, cbytes)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This works well enough for a demonstration, but it doesn't enforce strict timing, since the events will be scheduled whenever the thread wakes up.

How can I modify it to play the scale at a certain tempo with sample-accurate timing?

My assumption is that I need a way to make the synthesizer audio unit call a callback in my code before each render with the number of frames that are about to be rendered. Then I can schedule a MIDI event every "x" number of frames. You can add an offset, up to the size of the buffer, to the first parameter to `scheduleMIDIEventBlock`, so I could use that to schedule the event at exactly the right frame in a given render cycle.

I tried using `audioUnit.token(byAddingRenderObserver: AURenderObserver)`, but the callback I gave it was never called, even though the app was making sound. That method sounds like it's the Swift version of AudioUnitAddRenderNotify, and from what I read here, that sounds like what I need to do -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869149/11924045. How come it wouldn't be called? Is it even possible to make this "sample accurate" using Swift, or do I need to use C for that?

Am I on the right track? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  MIDI events can be scheduled with sample-accuracy in a render callback:

```
let sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()

...

let renderCallback: AURenderCallback = {
    (inRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer,
    ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBusNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>?) -> OSStatus in

    if ioActionFlags.pointee == AudioUnitRenderActionFlags.unitRenderAction_PreRender {
        let sampler = Unmanaged<AVAudioUnitSampler>.fromOpaque(inRefCon).takeUnretainedValue()

        let bpm = 960.0
        let samples = UInt64(44000 * 60.0 / bpm)
        let sampleTime = UInt64(inTimeStamp.pointee.mSampleTime)
        let cbytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 3)
        cbytes[0] = 0x90
        cbytes[1] = 64
        cbytes[2] = 127
        for i:UInt64 in 0..<UInt64(inNumberFrames) {
            if (((sampleTime + i) % (samples)) == 0) {
                sampler.auAudioUnit.scheduleMIDIEventBlock!(Int64(i), 0, 3, cbytes)
            }
        }
    }

    return noErr
}

AudioUnitAddRenderNotify(sampler.audioUnit,
                         renderCallback,
                         Unmanaged.passUnretained(sampler).toOpaque()
)
```

That used `AURenderCallback` and `scheduleMIDIEventBlock`.  You can swap in `AURenderObserver` and `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent`, respectively, with similar sample-accurate results:

```
let audioUnit = sampler.audioUnit

let renderObserver: AURenderObserver = {
    (actionFlags: AudioUnitRenderActionFlags,
    timestamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    frameCount: AUAudioFrameCount,
    outputBusNumber: Int) -> Void in

    if (actionFlags.contains(.unitRenderAction_PreRender)) {
        let bpm = 240.0
        let samples = UInt64(44000 * 60.0 / bpm)
        let sampleTime = UInt64(timestamp.pointee.mSampleTime)

        for i:UInt64 in 0..<UInt64(frameCount) {
            if (((sampleTime + i) % (samples)) == 0) {
                MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(audioUnit, 144, 64, 127, UInt32(i))
            }
        }
    }
}

let _ = sampler.auAudioUnit.token(byAddingRenderObserver: renderObserver)
```

Note that these are just examples of how it's possible to do sample-accurate MIDI sequencing on the fly.  You should still follow the [rules of rendering](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/508/?time=2952) to reliably implement these patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Sample accurate timing generally requires using the RemoteIO Audio Unit, and manually inserting samples at the desired sample position in each audio callback block using C code.

(A WWDC session on core audio a few years back recommended against using Swift in the audio real-time context.  Not sure if anything has changed that recommendation.)

Or, for MIDI, use a precisely incremented time value in each successive scheduleMIDIEventBlock call, instead of AUEventSampleTimeImmediate, and set these calls up slightly ahead of time.